# stripe checkout.js library not working in angular 8 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-universal

i upgraded to angular universal 8 and stripe checkout stopped working.
i added the libary in my index.html file

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

and in my component

```
handler: StripeCheckoutHandler;
```

but when i build my project i get this error

```
 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'StripeCheckoutHandler'.
```

Comment: checkout this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stripe). may be it will be helpful for you. or you can see the demo [here](https://w3path.com/angular-8-integrate-stripe-payment-gateway/).how to integrate and initialize the stripe payment through script injection.

Answer (score 0):

after hours of digging around the solution was to add

```
 @types/stripe-checkout
```

in tsconfig.app.json

```
"types": [
       
       "@types/stripe-checkout"
    ]
```